# How to get value from interface?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have :

```
public class UserContactInformation : IUserContactInformation
{
    public bool IsDefaultContactInformation { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

and interface:

```
public interface IUserContactInformation
{
    bool IsDefaultContactInformation { get; set; }
    string Email { get; set; }
    string Phone { get; set; }
}
```

How can I get email in controller because I don't see `UserContactInformation` in my controller. It's not visible. Do I need some function like `getEmail()`? I can`t use something like this:

```
model.Email = user.UserContactInformation.Email;
```

Comment: I guess it depends how you have specified your model in your view, have you specified your interface (IUserContactInformation) or your concrete class (UserContactInformation)?  If you have specified your interface, then `Email` will be accessible.  However, you will find that your code doesn't compile in it's current form, because you have specified `Email` in your interface and you haven't implemented it in your concrete class - which isn't valid.

Comment: im not sure that i understand you...i succeded to initialize values and now i try to print them...i dont know how to do that

Comment: because i cant use UserContactInformation.Email...its null

Comment: What error are you getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is currently invalid it won't compile because you can't have `Phone` defined in your interface and then fail to implement it in a class that has it defined.

```
public interface IUserContactInformation
{
    bool IsDefaultContactInformation { get; set; }
    string Email { get; set; }
    string Phone { get; set; }
}

// Invalid
public class UserContactInformation : IUserContactInformation
{
    public bool IsDefaultContactInformation { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}

// Valid
public class UserContactInformation : IUserContactInformation
{
    public bool IsDefaultContactInformation { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }

    // If this is in the interface, it needs to be implemented
    public string Phone { get; set; }
}
```

Secondly, if you want to print the `Email`, presumably within your view, you set the model in the view and then `print` it using razor syntax:

**ExampleView.cshtml:**

```
@model IUserContactInformation

<p>Hello, my email address is @Model.Email<p>
```

Comment: i added reference and now i see UserContactInformation but now i have problem to print values for that users....for example : model.Email= UserContactInformation.Email ? because i dont see Email and IsDefaultContactInformation ? if u know what i mean

Comment: becuase they are now in database and now i need to print them for that specific user...its like his personal information

Comment: What do you mean by you don't see it?

Comment: in my controller i need to say model.Email= ContactInformation.Email so that i can display it in view but i dont see property Email unless i made this    UserContactInformation userContactInformation = new UserContactInformation();
  model.Email= userContactInformation.Email; but then email is null...i dont get value

Comment: Does `userContactInformation.Email` have a value?  And yes, you can't access Email without `new`ing up an instance of it.  This is only possible if your class has the `static` modifier.

Comment: Yes, but in your code, when it runs, does it have a value??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79299/discussion-between-none-and-coulton).

Answer (score 0):

Interface: [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87d83y5b.aspx)

> A class or struct that implements the interface must implement the members of the interface that are specified in the interface definition

So, If you want to use it, create a instance and then use it:

```
var userContactInfo = new UserContactInformation();
model.Email = userContactInfo.Email;
```

Comment: i did that when i initialize values...but i now need to print them ...do i need to use same process?